# Cython: How to sort vector with closure

Tags: python, c++, lambda, migration, cython

I'm using latest Cython with C++17 flag (above C++11 to have closure syntax) to GCC. This C++ sort in Cython doesn't seem allowing closure:

```
# File: myfunc.pyx
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort

# cpdef to call from Python, it just wraps cdef anyway
cpdef myfunc():
    # int is just example, I need to sort struct vector
    cdef vector[int] v 
    v.push_back(2)
    v.push_back(1)

    # Compile error: Expected ')', found 'a'
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(), [](int a,int b){
        return a<b 
    })
```

**Is Cython supporting C++ closure and how to use it**? How to do C++ sort with closure coz I'm porting Python to Cython and there are a lot of lambda sorts.

Comment: I searched the C++ 17 standard documentation which is over 1000 pages, and I don't see `Cython` mentioned anywhere.  Why did you have the expectation that "cython" would adhere to the C++ standard?

Comment: for C++ closure which existed since C++11 (and without doubts, in C++17)

Comment: Go to [the authors](https://cython.org/) and ask them.  Do you have current code that uses lambdas in cython?  The issue would have nothing to do with `std::sort` and everything to do with non-support of what you are expecting.  Lambdas can exist without STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you don't actually need a "closure" - you don't capture any variables from the surrounding scope. Therefore for your particular example you could use a `cdef` function (which must be defined at the global scope):

```
cdef bool compare(double a, double b):
    return a<b

sort(v.begin(),v.end(), compare)
```

That obviously isn't a general solution. But a lot of the time passing a pointer to a C function really is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to search and alter the code but these are the only ways:

- Use .hpp header
- Or use 'sorted' function of Python

### Use .hpp header (.h is OK too if not using C++ feaures)

No C++ closure syntax in Cython as per my internet search, use struct with operator overload instead.

```
# File: mycmp.hpp
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(int a,int b){ return a<b; }
};
```

```
# File: myfunc.pyx
cdef extern from "mycmp.hpp":
    cdef struct cmp:
        bool "operator()"(int a,int b)

cdef vector[int] v
v.push_back(2)
v.push_back(1)

cdef cmp compare
sort(v.begin(),v.end(), compare)
print(v)
```

### Use 'sorted' function of Python

Because the `.sort` is not on `vector`, use `sorted` function instead. This is much simpler but for other kinds of lambda, maybe not applicable

```
v = sorted(v, key=lambda x: x) # x or some prop of x
```

Comment: Note that functors existed even before C++ was standardized, since all they do is wrap the call operator `operator()`.  That's probably why Cython supports this -- C++ has been able to do this since day 1.  What you wanted was something newly added to C++ after it was officially standardized, plus a revision later (C++ 03 didn't have lambdas).

Comment: yes, .hpp is just example